# Java/Scala Test collection framework

Tags: java, scala, tdd, bdd

I use a variety of tools for testing purposes: ScalaTest, JUnit, Specs2 etc.

I'm looking for a tool that is capable of:

- Storing test results in a database
- collecting test results
- running them across servers
- Has a simple UI with navigation

A perfect example is TestSwarm: http://swarm.jquery.org/, for JavaScript testing.

Is there such a framework available for the JVM world?

Comment: +1 for idea but this off topic.

Comment: I guess it could be done with jenkins and various plugins (e.g. [one of them is matrix builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Reloaded+Plugin)) (fixed link).

Comment: + 1, does not matter if its off topic, a good answer will be helpful.

Comment: The question isn't for an opinion, so is it still off-topic?

Comment: In ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it says "if your question  generally covers", and note the bullet point "software tools commonly used by programmers". This question is asking about a tool, so why is it off topic?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could write your own framework based on Specs2. Specs2 returns Result of an assertion, so it's possible to collect those results together afterwards. You can store them in DB with a full class name. Your test harness would work like map-reduce in this case, mapping tests to different servers, and then at the final step you would combine those results and produce a report.

I don't know of any tool like that. What is a practical purpose of such a thing?